# How do I move window buttons to the left in Budgie

Tags: window-manager, window-buttons, budgie

For a more consistent user experience between the different Ubuntu DEs I would like to have my windows buttons on the left side in Ubuntu Budgie.

Apparently the corresponding dconf key has no effect:

[image]

Comment: There appears to be a solution to this question at the bottom of this: https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop/issues/716

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### budgie-desktop 10.3

With budgie-desktop v10.3 the ability to switch the window buttons is built into Raven itself:

[image]

For 16.04 and 16.10 users budgie-desktop v10.3 is available via the normal updates mechanism.

For 17.04 users, open budgie-welcome, enable "backports" in the recommended software and then the desktop will be updated via the normal updates mechanism.

Alternatively:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntubudgie/backports
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop/issues/716), the following should work.

First, backup your current settings:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
```

Then, for apps with headerbars ("client side decorations"):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close,minimize,maximize,menu:'>}"
```

[image]

and for for those without them:

```
gsettings set com.solus-project.budgie-wm button-layout 'close,maximize,minimize,appmenu:'
```

Comment: Backup of settings always is a good idea but for default keys we have a "use default value" switch in dconf-editor.